# How to catch accents in the URL?

Tags: php

My users type URL's like:

www.mydomain.com/library/search/animals/**içara**

But when it gets to the PHP script, it becomes **iÃ§ara**.

Is there any way I can fix it before using this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you're getting this text. However, let's say you retrieve the text and place it within a variable called `$url`, using a variable from `$_SERVER`.

You could try [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo htmlentities($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```